# Desktop capture using directX 11

Tags: directx, screenshot, directx-11, directx-9, slimdx

I'm trying to capture desktop image using Direct 11 with SlimDX. But I don't know how to get the back buffer with directX 11 for the monitor desktop. I tried this with C# like this.Why doesn't it get the back buffer for the desktop?

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = false)]

static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

Device device1;

SwapChain swapChain1;

      var description1 = new SwapChainDescription()
            {
                BufferCount = 1,
                Usage = Usage.ReadOnly,
                OutputHandle = GetDesktopWindow(),
                IsWindowed = true,
                ModeDescription = new ModeDescription(0, 0, new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
                SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
                Flags = SwapChainFlags.AllowModeSwitch,
                SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Sequential
            };
Device.CreateWithSwapChain(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.None, description, out device1, out swapChain1);

var resource1 = Resource.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(swapChain1, 0);
 SlimDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D.SaveTextureToFile(context, resource1, ImageFileFormat.Png, "D:\\MyImage");
```

If not this way not work how can I capture desktop image with directX 11?
It will be really helpful if someone can answer.

Comment: Its not clear. Are you want backbuffer or monitor Desktop?

Comment: I want to get an image of desktop window with DirectX 11. So I need to get the back buffer of the desktop window. DirectX 9 has a function called "GetBackBuffer" to get the back buffer of the desktop. But I coudn't find any function or any way to get the back buffer of the desktop with DirectX 11.

Answer (score 0):

If you've created swapchain you can get any buffer, primary or secondary using swapchain.

```
D3D11.Texture2D backBuffer = swapChain.GetBackBuffer<D3D11.Texture2D>(0)
```

Second Method: In SlimDX you can get backbuffer using **Resource.FromSwapChain** method

```
using (var resource = Resource.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(swapChain, 0))
    renderTarget = new RenderTargetView(device, resource);
```

For details check out this link, this guy has explained it in detail https://slimdx.org/tutorials/DeviceCreation.php

Comment: But using this we can only get the back buffer of the swapChain we created. Isn't it?  How can I get the back buffer of the desktop?